# UIPageViewController with UITableView has strange size

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, constraints, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageViewController in my app with a UITableView. It works quite well, but when I turn pages, the next page seems to get resized (like it was too big before it finished loading): While turning the page, I can see the tableview being resized. When I slide only a bit (so I won't turn to the next page) a small section of the next page is showing.

UItableView Before the "slide a tiny bit"

[image: UITableView Before]

UITableView After the "slide a tiny bit"

[image: UITableView After]

When I complete the slide the UITableView will resize and the result will be the first image again. Only the resize can be seen with the eye (it's shaking)

My UITableView is using the following constraints:

[image: UITableView Constraints]

When I remove the UITableView constraints everything is working fine (except on an iphone bigger then 4s the height and width don't dynamicly change.

I noticed that during logging the width of the tableView.frame.size.width that sometimes the width is 336 instead of 320. (When I edit the constraints to -8 the width will be sometimes 320 instead of 304).

This is how I setup my PageViewController in my ViewController:

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (([self.roosterWeken count] == 0) || (index >= [self.roosterWeken count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];

    pageContentViewController.rooster = [self.roosterWeken objectAtIndex:index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    pageContentViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

The @"PageContentViewController" is an empty UIPageViewController with the following settings:

[image: UIPageViewController settings]

And the PageContentViewController looks like this in the storyboard:

[image: PageContentViewController]

Comment: I am getting the exact same problem! I will let you know if I find anything out :)

Comment: I have managed to fix it for myself! In the -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews... I simply call resize the tableView frame to be at 0,0... I tried to figure out the root cause of the problem but to no avail, so for now this works

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling a long time with this! It works! :D

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Taylor Abernethy Newman for his solution: In the PageViewController add the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    // sometimes the tableView width is higher then its parent
    if(frame.size.width > self.view.frame.size.width) {
        frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    }
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}
```